# Language with syntactic sugar that translates to C++ that looks "hand-written"

Tags: c++

I'm a college student and I have homework in C++.

My professor wants separate hpp and cpp files for each C++ class. And it just didn't feel good how much I had to type, and how much I had to click to create two new files for every class.

I haphazardly put together a [simple Python script](https://github.com/math4tots/classgen/blob/master/classgen.py) that would read a single file and generate all the needed classes (the easy stuff like class name, list of members, and list of things to #include I sprinkled with syntactic sugar, but the hard stuff to parse like typenames and function bodies I copied and pasted for the most part, except my script pokes around in a very primitive way to qualify method signatures with the class name when it generates the implementation file).

And I felt pretty good about it.

But I realized, that if a lot of other people had worked on a similar problem in the past, they probably could have done it better.

I know that Chicken scheme translates to C, and so does vala and genie, but from what I understand, with these sorts of translators, you don't really have full control over the C output.

Do you know of any translators that output C++ that largely keeps the semantics of C++ intact, so that the output C++ files look handwritten, but the source language is just loaded with wonderful syntax that makes life easier? Maybe even have the language mess with the body of functions so that if I typed something like `vector<int> v = [1,2,3,4,5]` it would become `vector<int> v; v.push_back(1); v.push_back(2); ..` in the generated source? Maybe have braces automatically inserted based on indentation? Have newlines serve as semicolons?

Comment: Typing is rarely the problem (esp. in C++). It's the retyping.

Comment: No. Autogenerated code is always going to look ugly because it's trying to handle millions of cases in as little code as possible. I'd suggest just sucking it up and writing C++. Getting a good editor can ease the pain however by autogenerating stubs and headers

Comment: Several things to consider: You will not be learning the material you are intended to be learning.  You may miss a point that the instructor is trying to teach and be critical for the next assignment.  Your code will be obviously generated (lack of good comments, good variable, method names).  It really isn't what you are trying to be taught.  Follow the path and see where it gets you - don't try to skip to the end.

Comment: The purpose of the class is follow the path to the end the instructor is trying to get you to, lets say "how to build a house".  You are trying to make prefab stud walls, which work well until they don't. And then, you won't know how to build a wall (much less where to put the electrical). And then when you are trying to learn how to do the electrical, you'll be missing the plumbing.  In the end, you'll know how to build a stud wall, but when hiring someone, I want to hire someone who can build a house to the plans I want - not make a stud wall prefabricator.

Comment: @jozefg I don't see why generated code has to necessarily be ugly. Especially if the source program is practically the same as the output program with some tedious bits filled in atuomatically. The variable names can be the same, and even comments and spacing between lines of code can be copied and pasted over, as I have done in my little script.

Comment: @math4tots Not necessarily, most major syntactical transformations demand some form of gensymed variables. What's `foo([1, 2, 3])`?.

Comment: @MichaelT I am not necessarily looking for a language that hides C++ goodies that go on under the hood. I want to be able to look at what I wrote and know exactly what C++ code will be generated. I just don't want to have to type `const some_namespace_qualify::sometype MyClass::myfunction(..) ..` and have to change it in two places when I need to change my function signature.

Comment: @jozefg I see what you mean, but I'm thinking more conservative, where you would rather not have a construct than have one where it's not obvious what the transformation should be. As for my thing about vectors above, I was thinking more along the lines of how in C in can write `int x[] = {1,2,3,4};` only for initialization. I think such conservative translators would be useful, especially if you would like your code to be directly compatible with C++ code, but still be reasonably DRY

Comment: @math4tots This sounds like a job for editor-foo rather than "whole new compiler"-foo. Consider emacs, I have several macros defined to do boiler-platey things when writing C++. Additionally C++11 helps much of this. `vector<int> foo = {1, 2, 3}`. C++11 + Editor-Foo should work out great

Comment: It sounds like you need to master the codebase of a  Chicken compiler . then you could use that as an API to generate where you need, tweak generation, hand-code some C++ and feed it back into the running compiler.  Basially a task that is just as much effort as just writing the thing in C++.

Comment: @AndyzSmith Chicken is generating assembly level C.

Comment: Since you know Python, you may find [Cog](http://www.python.org/about/success/cog/) to be of interest.

Comment: Eliminating headers is [planned](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/modules-update-on-work-in-progress-doug-gregor) for C++1y. But until then the preprocessor is simply too powerful for it's own good. You have to learn to deal with it and to that end you have to write it by hand. Even if modules make it to standard in 2017 they will take many more years to actually get implemented in all important platforms.

Answer (score 2):

No, a language like you are looking for is unlikely to exist.

I vaguely remember a few efforts to create new languages that tried to remove such warts out of C++ as header files, but invariably they are either compiled directly (no translation to C++) or the C++ they generate has a distinct machine-generated look and feel, because producing readable C++ wasn't (enough of) a requirement.

In most cases, the duplication that you get from having separate declarations and definitions is taken care of to a sufficient degree by advanced editor features, like macros, wizards and refactoring tools.